# Access root files with puma in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, puma-dev

When accessing my ssl certs with nginx from `/etc/ssl/`, everything works fine. But when I run rails development server (puma) as the normal user, it can't access the key in `/etc/ssl/private/` because of permissions.

How can I access `/etc/ssl/private` from the rails server? Do I need to add my user to a group or run the server with a different command?

Comment: Why does your Rails server need access to your private keys?

Comment: To server the site over SSL in development. Something has to perform the handshake.

Comment: Why do you need SSL for your development environment?

Comment: To test services that connect to the server that require SSL. I did debate on this as being unnecessary and introducing more things to maintain, but it really is more thorough and production-like.

Comment: That's the way it is now. However, nginx gets them from `/etc/ssl` (standard location), so I'd like it to be as similar as possible... otherwise I'm passing in a file path based on environment, which is messier.

Comment: You're trying to run a Rails test suite that relies on external services connecting to your Rails server by SSL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194648/discussion-between-user8897013-and-anothermh).

Comment: Will the tests work with an anonymous (self-signed) certificate? I think Puma would allow SSL without a valid signed signature (iodine does, so I might be assuming).

Comment: I don't think the issue is about the certificate being valid, it has to do with where it is located on the server and whether puma/nginx can access it. Nginx can (it runs as www-data), but not puma (runs as a normal user - i.e. `rails server ...`).